# Green's functions and spectral function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

I'm struggling to understand something in the book by Fetter & Walecka, p.295, relating to the causal ($G$), advanced ($G^A$) and retarded ($G^R$) Green's functions, and the spectral function ($\rho$).

In the book it says that

$G(k,\omega) = [1\mp e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}]^{-1}G^R(k,\omega) + (1\mp e^{\beta\hbar\omega}]^{-1} G^A(k,\omega)$

and

$\text{Im}\;G^R(k,\omega) = -\tfrac{1}{2}\rho(k,\omega)$

$\text{Im}\;G^A(k,\omega) = \tfrac{1}{2}\rho(k,\omega)$

$\text{Im}\;G(k,\omega) = -\tfrac{1}{2} [\tanh (\tfrac{1}{2}\beta\hbar\omega)]^{\mp 1} \rho(k,\omega)$

However, when I sum $\text{Im}\;G^R$ and $\text{Im}\;G^A$, together with the exponential prefactors from the first equality, I am unable to obtain $\text{Im}\;G = -\tfrac{1}{2} [\tanh (\tfrac{1}{2}\beta\hbar\omega)]^{\mp 1} \rho$.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: you just need $\frac{1}{1\pm \mathrm e^{+a}}-\frac{1}{1\pm \mathrm e^{-a}}=-\tanh(a/2)^{\pm1}$, which is almost the definition of $\tanh$ (after combining denominators)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That's an answer on its own right.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty yes, its an answer. But I am unsure whether I should actually post it as an answer or not, because IMHO the question is kind of off-topic (its just about mathematics: there are no phyisics here)